# Mysterious durations with PDO/MySQL when using utf8

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8, pdo

I'm building a webapp which uses PHP / PDO-MySQL, but I've got a problem with the generation time of my page. The database is fully set to utf8, but when I use `PDO::quote()` it takes about 1 second to quote a string. (which is to long...)

When I use `SET NAMES utf8` to set the charset (thus it's set in my.ini), `PDO::quote()` only takes 0.00001 seconds, **but** `SET NAMES utf8`takes 1 second. Well, how can I reduce *both* durations?

---

- PHP version: *5.4.3*
- MySQL version: *5.5.24*

Comment: This is caused by network latency, I suppose. Can you confirm the problem is only happen for the FIRST query? Subsequent query is better?

Comment: I don't think so, I run it on localhost...

Comment: Is your MySQL also running on localhost?

Comment: Yes,  PHP, Apache and MySQL are running on localhost

Comment: You should use the charset parameter in the PDO connection string rather than calling a query. But I think there is a fundamental resource problem. What are the query execution times if you run them via the mysql client?

Comment: I think you're right. When I run `SET NAMES utf8` over console, execution time is 0.000sec. When I append `;charset=utf8` to my connection string and remove `SET NAMES utf8`, `PDO::quote` is slow. When I remove this quote, the next query is slow... I think the first action PDO performs is slow all the time :/